Copy first attribute value and then create a new attribute with value of first attribute
I have a huge amount of files with elements containing an id. I would like to copy the value of the id and create a new attribute with the value of the id:
<element id="some_unique.value">
    ...      
</element>

What I'm trying to achieve:
<element id="some_unique.value" new_attribute="some_unique.value">
    ...      
</element>

How can I do this using a regular expression? I'm looking for a regex that I can use in my IDE (Visual Studio Code) to quickly change multiple files.

something like this?

[tag:regex]: "Specify the language or tool that you are using." Also note regex is famously not the best tool for parsing XML.

A regular expression might be part of the solution, but surely you will need to write a script in another language to read and write the files? For example, you could write a Javascript program to be run on Node.js. Or are you after a single grep command to do the lot? Which language are you hoping to use? Please edit your post to include these details.

I updated my question with information on what kind of regex I'm looking for. Thank you.

@DuesserBaest Exactly. It works as intented - please make it an answer. Thank you.

As in my comment try matching:
id="([^"]+)"

and replace with
$0 new_attribute="$1"

See: regex101

Explanation
Match:

id="...": match literal id and text in quotation

([^"]+): that is not quotation marks. save this to group 1



Replace:

$0: keep original data
 new_attribute=": add literal ' new_attribute='
": open quotation
$1: insert group 1 (quoted id text) and
": close quotation


Capture the part you want to reuse as a group and use a back reference to construct the result.
Search:
<element id="([^"]+)"

Replace:
$0 new_attribute="$1"

Group 0 is the entire match.
